# Enterprise architect dynamically change text appearance based on tag value

Tags: templates, document, enterprise-architect, dynamically-generated

I am not sure how to do this.
I am using a table to create a data dictionary.
For each data item name, if it has a certain tag value, I'd like to change the color and italicize the font.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't (easily). The font can only be changed from the context menu for a single diagram element (either globally of for the very diagram). Shape script does not offer changes to the font. Only the color can be changed with `SetFontColor`. In any case, a font change affects any text in a diagram element. You can not highlight e.g. a single attribute.

What can be done is to implement an add-in that can change the font for single elements based on some implemented rule. The easiest would be to run a "global-change" macro that goes through all diagram-/elements and sets the font.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas.  I didn't make it clear that I want to do this for the output in a Word document generated via EA.  Does that change your answer at all?

Comment: No, that won't change the answer. What you see in Word is just a physical rendering of the diagram. So you first have to create the right display format - which is not possible for named reasons.